# User Not be Sent to Front Page after Submitting Contact Form

Tags: emails

After submitting contact form (on contact page), the user automatically is sent (redirected) to front page. How can I avoid it? (user remain on contact page)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use form_state['redirect'] in your form alter,

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == ''contact_us_form) {
      $form_state['redirect'] = array('contact/us');
  }
}
```

Comment: You could use a more _dynamic path_ than `contact/us` with a function like [current_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/current_path/7). That way, it should work even if you change the path to something else, or if you use translated pages i18n. However, it won't work if you want to send the user to another page then the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Rule](http://drupal.org/project/rules) on webform submission and redirect user to front page.